# How to get or identify unique id or descriptor from Azure devops Profile REST API

Tags: api, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, profile

I'm not getting the "descriptor" in Profile API response. This I need to save in database to identify whether he/she is a returning user on our web portal or a new user.

Did some research on Azure devops REST APIs to find that, there is something called "descriptor" which is a unique id for any user on Azure devops platform.

For that, I tried Profile REST API endpoint - https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=7.0

I need this descriptor or unique id because to identify whether a user is returning user or new user based on which I can create account or simply sign in. In other words, I'm implementing Oauth flow to Signup with Azure devops.

However, I get some "id" in Profile API response but that is not unique across different Azure devops accounts or organizations.

Any ideas on how to get "descriptor"? can we get in Profile API? or any other API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically I'm playing around with Azure devops APIs to get the "descriptor" for authenticated user ( Oauth flow). The problem here is I'm not getting "descriptor" for authenticated user via Profile API.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to get "descriptor"?

We cannot get the "`descriptor`" using the [Profiles API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).

To get the "`descriptor`" we can use [Users - List - REST API (Azure DevOps Graph)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

[image]

Alternately, we can use the following REST API for the currently logged in user:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/connectiondata`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the API endpoints which you suggested contain {organization} in URL parameters. In our case, we want to get the profile details including descriptor for the authenticated user where the {organization} is unknown or can be anything. What do you say?

Comment: @AlwaysMember I am afraid that there isn't an API can get the `descriptor` directly without the `{organization}` parameter. With the [Profiles API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP), we can get the user ID `"id":"5e03ebd5-e4d6-6eb8-ae70-1axxxxxxxx2"`, it's also unique.